# Dynamical Generation of Complex Mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, complex-numbers

Under what conditions is it possible for a theory of massless elementary particles to dynamically generate a complex valued mass $m=x+iy$ with $y\neq 0$? This would necessarily make the massless theory inconsistent. I suspect this might have something to do with unitarity or locality.

Comment: Just to be clear: here you have in mind a 4d gauge theory of massless fermions, right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I kept it arbitrary in case there was an interesting example. For instance, maybe something happens in a Nambu-Jona-Lasinio type model. But we can focus on the type of theory you mention.